# Is there a Alternative to optimistic locking

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, nosql

I'm working on a project where we collect (last_x, counters ) information about a account.
User actions could result in multiple business events being generated. When a single user action on the web, results in more than one event, it will trigger an update to USER HISTORY table.

We do optimistic locking to make sure the all the events result in a update to USER HISTORY table.

**Problem:**

Optimistic locking results in extra reads ( when conflicts are detected, read again and update ) and extra writes ( after resolving the conflict).

**Solutions Tried:**

- Every event results in insert to USER HISTORY Table
      - More history information, results in poor read performance.

Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Can you just write records instead of updating? Therefore no potential for clashes.

Comment: Writes will result in one to one mapping between user events in website to a record in user history table. Since it is a table that has counter variables, and last_X variables. we need the latest record. which means we have to sort all the events before loading. which will result in poor read performance.

Comment: How is important that it's updated immediately?

Comment: Couple of seconds delay is okay I guess. But which event will wait when there are multiple events?

Answer (score 2):

Is there an overriding **need** to have read performance on this table?

It sounds to me like it is some sort of 'end of business day'/every hour or so, customer profile/intelligence table. If this is the case, then you could just use inserts and think about datawarehousing techniques, such as a [Star Schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema) to look after the (last_x, counters) side of things.

If it's more critical and time dependent then your schema is probably not up for the job. Have you considered using messaging middleware such as [JMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service) to notify and trigger other business events?

Since your using Oracle you could look at: [Oracle AS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_16/web.1012/b14012/jms.htm)

[EDIT] Based on discussion, you have a realtime producer/consumer of counter information. I don't think the database is the base way to go about this. You may need to hold onto the counters for accounting purposes, so maybe something like this is what you need:

**Producer**: init(rebuild session/memcached from DB)
               RECV User Action X -> Session/Memcached(ActionX) + Insert to DB.

**Consumer**: running(check session/memcached for condition, act)

You could even make the consumers of the user history counters be subscribers to an event that is triggered by the producer when counters reach X and remove consumer dependency on USER HISTORY

Comment: Datawarehousing is not a option , because we need real time data. We use JMS, which triggers a write. If there are multiple events, then they trigger simultaneous write to the same record. We resolve the conflict with optimistic locking, but that results in excessive read and writes. We want to avoid that.

Comment: Is the requirement to read the history table realtime? Is there something else that needs be be kicked off if the counter reaches a certain level? Basically, is writing to the history table and acting on the history table two different things? History needs to be there for accounting, but something needs to happen immediately if counter hits X?

Comment: Yes, we do take actions based on counters and lifetime of variables.

Comment: So, why can't the counters be held in the session, written by insertion into the history table, but acted on (possible using JMS) when session counter hits target value? If everything goes to the wall, you can recover

Comment: Then it won't be real time for consumer's of USER HISTORY table.

Comment: Yeah, but you could use the session counters/memcached (if it's distributed) and have consumer's of USER HISTORY try that as first port of call. The history is maintained for recovery in HISTORY TABLE, with a little overhead to get started again.

Comment: Let me see whether I get this right. If events happened in last 5 minutes. Then be in cache. after 5 minutes move it to DB?

Comment: Well you could do that, but you could just put them straight into the DB, you are only really using the DB to recover the producer(s) or hold history as the name suggests. The counter statistics are rolling aggregates maintained in memory/memcached for speed and used to determine condition X, whether the consumers use memcached or are notified is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to be like these multiple events are following different path and each event results in a history record. Is that correct?

Shouldn't the application be able to control the events and somehow indicate its the same event following different paths? Like maybe generate a unique ID for every event and make the field unique in the DB so that writes will fail? You can easily ignore fails because of the unique constraint.

Comment: Yes. different event follows different path. so they have no idea of the other. Yes, we have a retry logic, but that results in more reads and writes. We are trying to avoid that scenario.

Comment: In that case, why can't you generate a UNIQUE identifier for each event and pass that identifier to every cloning of that event? In that case, the DB will simply handle the unique constraint (assuming you can make your schema to enforce unique constraint on the ID of the event) by ignoring multiple writes with the same unique ID.

Comment: If the event ID is a part of the unique key, then it will avoid the unique constraint violation. But, what if the event A read from DB before Event B wrote. In that case Event A is updating outdated information and when it writes we lose Event B's information, because unique constrain won't fail because of the event ID.

Comment: I was under the impression you wanted to log each event only once even if it took different paths. It looks like you are interested in logging all the paths to the event as different entries. Then why is it a problem when you have multiple writes? In this case, each path is a different record. Maybe I am not following your question.